# When providing estimate for software development, are QA hours paid by the same rate as development, or by a different rate?

Tags: testing, estimation

Lets say we tell our client that we work for $20/h as software developers. Lets say that this project will take 100 hours of development, and another guy in our company is going to need 20 hours to QA the product (and a manager is going to need 10 hours to manage the project)

Now, do we charge them for 130 hours * $20 or do we charge them for 100 hours * $20 and then 20 hours * QA_rate and 10 hours * Manager_rate?

I looked at this SO question, but nothing is mentioned about money: [estimating of testing effort as a percentage of development time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595346/estimating-of-testing-effort-as-a-percentage-of-development-time)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a technical question, but a business question. It's up to the company making the offer to define its rate policy, and up to the client to decide whether or not to accept the offer. There's no single right way to do this.

Comment: While I'm not voting ... it *is* more a matter for your cost-accountants than for technical developers. We charge a single rate for time, whether that is QA or development, because the two activities are very similar in terms of required expertise, etc, as well as the effort of it.

Comment: Not only that, be a price is not only a function of cost, but also of what you can actually get the customer to pay :)